# Ionic 2 - *ngFor random shuffles between values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic2

I want to show quotes in a `div element` thereby I would like to update that quote every 5 minutes or something. But when I create an `*ngFor` in the html it will show all the elements of the array. Is there a way to show a randomly picked quote in the array every 5 min?

Here is my ts file where I create the array:

```
  public quotesArray: any[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.quotesArray.push('testQuote');
    this.quotesArray.push('testQuote2');
    this.quotesArray.push('testQuote3');
    this.quotesArray.push('testQuote4');
  }
```

and here is the html:

```
<div *ngFor="let q of quotesArray; let i = index">{{ q }}</div>
```

How can I pick a random quote every 5 minutes?

Comment: Assuming your quotes are coming from a server why don't you just make an http request every 5 minutes for a new quote?

Comment: They are for now not coming from a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `*ngFor` does, it iterates through and array and prints on the screen the html created inside it the number of times as the length of the array.

If you want to show just ONE quote at a time and update it every 5 minutes you can use the `setInterval()` method to manipulate the quote.

```
public quotesArray: any[] = [];
public randomQuote: string;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  this.quotesArray.push('testQuote');
  this.quotesArray.push('testQuote2');
  this.quotesArray.push('testQuote3');
  this.quotesArray.push('testQuote4');

  // immediately show one random quote;
  this.quotesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quotesArray.length)];

  setInterval(() => {
    this.randomQuote = this.quotesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.quotesArray.length)]; // this'll get the quote depending on your array length
  }, 300000); // needs to be in milliseconds
}
```

And in your html you'll have

```
<div>{{randomQuote}}</div>
```

As Daniel Cooke commented, if the quotes come from a server you could call it every 5 minutes, just need to implement the code inside the setInterval.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: But this will not show the value inmediatly, this shows only the value after 5 min. So the value has to display and than change after 5 min

Comment: edited the answer, just immediately give a quote to the variable